# Android - Passing Params to the RESTful URL in Android app

Tags: java, android, url, restful-url

I am developing an android application which involves passing parms.I want to pass parameters to url in android.

How to pass parms to RESTful URL in an Android app using EditText field. Also give me the basic example for both get and post method webservice calling and passing parms in android.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
            b.setClickable(false);
            new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
        }
        private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
            protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
               InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                 StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                 int n = 1;
                 while (n>0) {
                     byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                     n =  in.read(b);
                     if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
                 }
                 return out.toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                 String st1=null;
                 String st2=null;

                 EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                 EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                 st1= et1.getText().toString();
                 st2= et2.getText().toString();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency="+st1+"&ToCurrency="+st2);
                 Log.d("url", httpGet.toString());
                 Log.d("et1", et1.toString());
                 Log.d("et2", et2.toString());
                String text = null;
                 try {
                       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                       text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     return e.getLocalizedMessage();
                 }
                 return text;
            }   

            protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
                if (results!=null) {
                    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
                    et.setText(results);
                }
                Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
                b.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
        }

    activity_main.xml:

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Http GET Demo"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="GET"
            android:id="@+id/my_button"/>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="15"
            android:maxLines="15"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:editable="false"
            android:id="@+id/my_edit"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I got error as unfortunately stoped.

Comment: You can't access UI elements in doInBackground as said by that answer. Use onPreExecute.

Comment: @OzgurGUL. But the above code is working for me. earlier I wrote it as a  st1= et1.toString();
st2= et2.toString(); there I got error as unfortunately stoped. but now changed it into st1= et1.getText().toString();
st2= et2.getText().toString(); it is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `doInBackground` have following lines:

```
....
st1= et1.getText().toString();
st2= et2.getText().toString();
```

causing issue because `et1` and `et1` is UI elements, so we can access these Views from only UI Thread instead of from any background Thread which is used in `doInBackground` for doing Task in separate Thread.

Use `onPreExecute` method to get data from `EditText` :

```
String st1=null;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        st1= et1.getText().toString();
        // do same for other
    }
```

Now use `st1` String inside `doInBackground` to get user input text.

Comment: Above my coding is working good.Earlier I wrote it as a st1= et1.toString(); st2= et2.toString(); there I got error as unfortunately stoped. but now changed it into st1= et1.getText().toString(); st2= et2.getText().toString(); it is working for me.